# In python how to convert string to datetime with timezone

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I am getting value error while converting string to datetime. Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_str = "2018-07-13T17:12:02-0500"
>>> t = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
t = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 324, in _strptime
(bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

>>> t = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
t = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2018-07-13T17:12:02-0500' does not match format '%Y- 
%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'
>>>
```

I am using python version 2.7.14

Comment: are you specifically looking for Python 2.7 version answer? because your code works for Python 3.X

Comment: @Surya Tej Yes, specific for python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
iso_ts = '2012-11-01T04:16:13-04:00'
datetime.strptime(''.join(iso_ts.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 4, 16, 13, 
tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```

Comment: am using python 2.7 version... am getting same value error..

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.